# What calcutaing algorithm use for a product with unlimited possible properties?

Tags: database, algorithm, math

We have a product Xitem, which can have properties Aprop, Bprop, Cprop, and etc unlimited.
For example, let's take a product "Tree". This product may have properties:

- Variety of tree `["Persian", "Siberian"]`
- Tree's age `["From 5 years old", "From 10 years old", "From 25 years old"]`

Also, for the product there may be limiters (unlimited), like:

- Quantity in stock
- The seller of the product
- Country/climate where it grew up and where it will be delivered from

Each selected property affects to final price of the product.
By default, product properties are not selected. And there is another rules:

- Products may have a base price
- Or products may not have a base price and the price depends from selected properties

Also, some limiters may affect to final price or price for extra services:

- Quantities from *N* or *M* numbers give a discount or affect to a base price
- The seller of a product can sell the same product cheaper or more expensive
- The country of delivery may affect to the price of delivery

**These properties can be unlimited**
**We can create an entity "property type" that tells to a program how to calculate**

Question:
What algorithm of actions is better to use for not create a mess?
I mean, what schema for database to create, fields in the tables and how to operate with them?

Comment: You cannot have infinite properties unless you have infinite storage.  All you can have in practice are the actually existing properties, and careful checks for storage overflow.  Have procedures for adding new properties rather than trying to start with an infinite number.

Comment: You probably mean to say "without limit" or just "unlimited" instead of "Infinity".  "Infinity" only exists in mathematical theories, it cannot exist in reality and no computer program can process an infinite amount of input.

Comment: Yes, my mistake... Unlimited possible properties

Comment: You mistyped Calcutta.